# IE7 mode in IE8 - localStorage is not undefined

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7, local-storage

I'm writing a small localstorage script with cookie fallback. So far so good, i switch to IE7 mode inside IE8 and enter `localStorage` in the console expecting it to return `undefined`
But it returns an object `{...}`

Is this normal? If yes, is there anyway for me to test my script without Virtual Machines?

Comment: Make sure you switch both the `Browser Mode` and `Document Mode`. One affects the JavaScript engine, the other affects (among other things) the user agent string. Having inconsistent values for browser/document mode may cause your code to behave strangely if it's doing browser detection (opposed to feature detection).

Comment: I did, Document Mode was set to `IE7 Standards` during the test
http://i41.tinypic.com/6teb8z.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching document modes etc is unreliable for feature detection testing. It's really only good for a quick render test.

The most reliable way to test browser issues is with a VM. You can [download](http://www.modern.ie/) pre-configured VM's for IE testing or you could use a cloud based solution such as http://www.browserstack.com/.